# Displaying an UIImageView property from another class programmatically

Tags: objective-c, properties, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

Well, here's the situation: 
I've got...

- a custom class with an `UIImageView`-property, let's call it the `Enemy`-class
- a `ViewController`
- a `NSMutableArray` to help create multiple instances of `Enemy` (called `enemies`)

and what I want:

- be able to create an unlimited amount of `Enemy`-Instances through a method in my `ViewController` (like `[self spawnEnemy];`, where `self` is the `ViewController`)
- and, subsequently, display the `UIImageView` property (let's call it "`enemyImage`") on the `view` that is controlled by my `ViewController`

I've tried something like this:

```
-(Enemy *) spawnEnemy
 {
   Enemy *tempEnemy = [Enemy new];
   [enemies addObject:(Enemy*)tempEnemy];
   [self.view addSubview:(UIImageView*)[[enemies objectAtIndex:[enemies count]] enemyImage]];

   //randomLocation is declared in the Enemy-Class and just assigns a random 
   //CGPoint to self.enemyImage.center 
   [[enemies objectAtIndex:[enemies count]] randomLocation];

   return [[enemies objectAtIndex:[enemies count]]createEnemy];
 }
```

This runs without errors, `randomLocation` gets called (tried with NSLog), AND if I do something like this in another Method of `ViewController`:

```
[[self spawnEnemy] enemyTestMethod];
```

enemyTestMethod is being executed as well.

**But still, no `enemieView`s are displayed on the screen...**
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much for your help and time.

==== Edit ====

Here's the relevant code from Enemy.h/Enemy.m:

```
@interface Enemy : NSObject
{
    UIImageView *enemyImage;   
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *enemyImage;

-(Enemy*) createEnemy;

//Enemy.m

@implementation Enemy

@synthesize enemyImage, speed;

-(Enemy *) createEnemy
{
    self.enemyImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [self.enemyImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"enemy.png"]];
    return self;
}
```

I also corrected the last line in the `spawnEnemy`-Method to properly send createEnemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't include the code in `Enemy` where you alloc/init the `UIImageView` property. Unless this code explicitly specifies a `CGRect` with the `size` and `origin` that you want, the view will be initialized with `CGRectZero`, which means even if you're correctly adding the subview (and it looks like you are) you still won't see it anywhere.

Post the `Enemy` code, and the problem will probably be immediately apparent.

Comment: That could in fact be the problem. I edited the OP accordingly.

Comment: YEP, indeed :D  After calling `[self.enemyImage setFrame:CGRect]` in the `createEnemy` method it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

<s>Have you called -createEnemy before you added them to your view?</s>

OK, you've got this checked.

Then maybe you should check as @MusiGenesis suggested.

To do this, you need to inspect the properties of your enemyImage.

You can do this in either of the following ways:

1. print its frame.size by:

   NSLog(@"enemyImage frame size: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(enemy.enemyImage));
2. set a breakpoint where you feel great, and check with your debugger:

   p (CGRect)[[enemy enemyImage] frame]

Comment: I already tried to call [tempEnemy createEnemy] before I added it to the array, but that didn't change anything...